# PHP - search multi dimesional array with multiple values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My function search inside a multi dimensional array for a match. It works but I would like to know if there is a better way to do that.

```
$arrays = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'color_id' => 2, 'store_id' => 1),
    array('id' => 1, 'color_id' => 2, 'store_id' => 2),
    array('id' => 2, 'color_id' => 3, 'store_id' => 1)
);

function query_array($array, $keys = array(), $values = array()){
    $match = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
        for($x = 0; $x < count($keys); $x++){
            if($array[$i][$keys[$x]] == $values[$x]){
                $match[$i][] = 'increment';
                if(count($match[$i]) == count($keys)){
                    return $array[$i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $match;
}
$searchKeys = array('item_id', 'store_id');
$searchValues = array(2,1);
$match = query_array($arrays, $searchKeys, $searchValues);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($match);
echo '<pre>';
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php ?

Comment: Thanks. This one worked for me
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#106107

Comment: @MikeHins Welcome to SO, if you didn't already know you are allowed to answer your own question and accept your own answer.  It may at some point help others, but it also closes the question (which keeps the site organised) :)